# Why can't I assign random values in a loop?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to implement the following:

```
for (( i=1; i<=sim_users; i++))
do
   value[$i] = $RANDOM
done
```

why dosen't this work?

Comment: If the answer to this question helped, please accept it (use the check mark button). The same is valid for your other questions (see your [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/713083/chanditha-karunnyake) for a list).

Comment: It's generally a good idea to tell us exactly *how* it doesn't work.  Show us what output you got (and, if it's not obvious, what output you want).  This one was fairly obvious, but your next question might not be.

Answer (score 7):

You want

```
value[$i]=$RANDOM
```

You can't put a space before or after the equals sign.